# Swagger UI does not render properly in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a swagger.js specification file like this:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  swaggerDefinition: {
    swagger: '2.0',
    info: {
      title: 'test API',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'test server endpoints'
    },
    basePath: '/',
    schemes: ['http', 'https'],
    securityDefinitions: {
      Bearer: {
        type: 'apiKey',
        in: 'header',
        name: 'Authorization',
        description:
          'For accessing the API a valid JWT token must be passed in all the queries in the Authorization header.' +
          'The following syntax must be used in the Authorization header :' +
          'Bearer xxxxxx.yyyyyyy.zzzzzz'
      }
    }
  },
  apis: ['./server/*.js'] //this is the apis file
};
```

and my app.js looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');

const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerOption = require('./swagger');
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(swaggerOption);

var routes = require('./server/http_service');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));

app.listen(3000);
```

When I try to access localhost:3000/api-docs, the swagger ui does not render properly, sometimes it also render the raw html of swagger-ui. Which part am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

[swagger ui is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrX7x.png)
[swagger ui renders raw html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qDMD.png)

Comment: are you sure `swaggerOption` is correctly importing?

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: hi @xMayank the `swaggerOption` comes from the swagger.js, which is in the same directory as app.js. May i know what is your version of installed swagger-ui-express and swagger-jsdoc? thankyou

Comment: ` "swagger-jsdoc": "^4.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",`

Comment: @xMayank thankyou :) will give it another try

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate, but it is working fine here by my side. 
But anyways, I tried to setup a little example in swagger with how much information and code you have provided us with. 
And here what we have came up with: https://gitlab.com/sistemaon/stackoverflow-eqa/-/tree/master/swagger-ui-does-not-render-properly-in-nodejs

Only one thing that I would suggest is to use swagger version 3.0.0, which is openapi now, instead using swagger version 2.0. So you may use [components](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) to define and reuse your resources, as well you will have your swagger documentation up to date.

Hope this may help you!

Comment: thankyou very much for you help will try out swagger 3.0.0!